# Schedule notification every day in exact time

Tags: ios, uilocalnotification, swift3

I'm trying to show notification everyday in exact time, but it's firing sometimes few times for an hour, or not firing at all 0_o

```
let not = UILocalNotification()
not.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName
not.alertBody = "Time to stop drink!"
not.fireDate = Calendar.current.date(bySettingHour: HOUR, minute: MINUTE, second: 0, of: Date(), options: Calendar.Options())
not.repeatInterval = Calendar.Unit.day
UIApplication.shared().scheduleLocalNotification(not)
```

Comment: You need to set localNotification timezone to current timezone. Don't forget to cancel previously scheduled notifications.

Comment: @LeoDabus that seems to work now, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @LeoDabus, I added just one line `not.timeZone = TimeZone.default` and it's working now